# JWPlayer - Why does a single video plays on its own but not when put in playlist?

Tags: jwplayer6

I am experiencing some odd behavior where I can play a video file but the same video file generates an error when put into a playlist.

JWPlayer 6.9.4867 (pro version)

Called in  tag

```
  <!-- jwplayer code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/content/js/jwplayer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer.key = "---key here---";</script>
```

The following code works fine.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
 file: "http://www.artistshare.com/media_proxy.aspx?id=23745&ex=.mp4&mediaTypeID=4",
 type: "mp4",
 width: 980,
 height: 350,
 image: "http://www.artistshare.com/images/projects/531/16531.jpg",

});
```

When converted to a playlist it does not. Media will not load. "Error loading player: No playable sources found"

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jwplayer("myElement").setup({
 playlist: [{
 image: "http://www.artistshare.com/images/projects/531/16531.jpg",
 file: "http://www.artistshare.com/media_proxy.aspx?id=23745&ex=.mp4&mediaTypeID=4", title: "Testing"
 }],

 height: 350,
 width: 980,
 listbar: {
 position: 'right',
 size: 260
 },

 });

 </script>
```

Has anyone else experienced this?  Seems like a bug but maybe I am missing something.   Any insight would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the type needs to be specified type: "mp4" in the playlist array.  Silly mistake but hopefully this will help someone.